# open telemetry can't ingest dynatrace from aws lambda function with AWS Distro for OpenTelemetry

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, open-telemetry, dynatrace

We use AWS Distro for OpenTelemetry

arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:901920570463:layer:aws-otel-nodejs-amd64-ver-1-5-0:1

We did a basic aws lamda function:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const url = 'http://checkip.amazonaws.com/';

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    let response
    console.log('[START] - OpenTelemetry / Dynatrace');
    try {
        response = await axios({
            method: 'post', url:url
        });
        console.log('**************', response?.data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('ERR: ', error)
    }
    console.log('[END] - OpenTelemetry / Dynatrace');
    return response?.data;
}
```

Our collector.yaml config is

[collector.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2gIS.png)

```
# Token QA ( Ingest Opentelemetry Traces ):
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:55680
      http:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:55681
exporters:
  otlphttp:
    endpoint: "https://ico19512.live.dynatrace.com/api/v2/otlp/v1/traces"  
    headers: {Authorization: "Api-Token dt0c01......"}
service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [otlphttp]
```

Our enviroments variables

[enviroments variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWC0e.png)

Our lamda run ok, but we don't see ingested nothing.

Aws Lambda Response is ok:
"34.237.128.180\n"

Function Logs

```
START RequestId: b077aa35-b4bc-4604-8e5a-c67dbfa454ac Version: $LATEST
EXTENSION   Name: collector State: Ready    Events: [INVOKE,SHUTDOWN]
{"level":"debug","msg":"Received ","event :":"{\n\t\"eventType\": \"INVOKE\",\n\t\"deadlineMs\": 1660236861439,\n\t\"requestId\": \"b077aa35-b4bc-4604-8e5a-c67dbfa454ac\",\n\t\"invokedFunctionArn\": \"arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:658913498668:function:dyna-otel\",\n\t\"tracing\": {\n\t\t\"type\": \"X-Amzn-Trace-Id\",\n\t\t\"value\": \"Root=1-62f5342f-1b4ce6bd6c1ebf2c6601dc57;Parent=29fc70b85a8376fd;Sampled=0\"\n\t}\n}"}
{"level":"debug","msg":"Waiting for event..."}
2022-08-11T16:54:09.465Z    b077aa35-b4bc-4604-8e5a-c67dbfa454ac    INFO    [START] - OpenTelemetry / Dynatrace
2022-08-11T16:54:09.806Z    b077aa35-b4bc-4604-8e5a-c67dbfa454ac    INFO    ************** 34.237.128.180

2022-08-11T16:54:09.806Z    b077aa35-b4bc-4604-8e5a-c67dbfa454ac    INFO    [END] - OpenTelemetry / Dynatrace
END RequestId: b077aa35-b4bc-4604-8e5a-c67dbfa454ac
REPORT RequestId: b077aa35-b4bc-4604-8e5a-c67dbfa454ac  Duration: 708.69 ms Billed Duration: 709 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 126 MB Init Duration: 1324.55 ms

Request ID
b077aa35-b4bc-4604-8e5a-c67dbfa454ac
```

Comment: Hi, ADOT PM here. When you say ingest I'd like to understand what? Like are you trying to ingest [traces](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/extend-dynatrace/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-traces/opentelemetry-ingest/opent-nodejs) or [metrics](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/partners/dynatrace)?

Comment: Hi Michael, we are starting with opentelemetry, at the moment we want to ingest traces, when we are successful our idea is to continue with metrics.
If you have any related basic examples, please send them.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the clarification! So, I don't see anywhere in your code where you're actually emitting traces. As mentioned, if you follow https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/extend-dynatrace/opentelemetry/opentelemetry-traces/opentelemetry-ingest/opent-nodejs then this should work, let me know please?

Comment: The URL for the `otlphttp` exporter is also wrong. It has to be the base path. For Dynatrace, that should be: `https://{your-environment-id}.live.dynatrace.com/api/v2/otlp`. You can see a full example here: https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/extend-dynatrace/opentelemetry/basics/collector#example-configuration